# How to autofill date in google sheet when i enter value in cell A

Tags: google-sheets

If I enter "paid" text in cell A in sheet, I want to auto pull the current date in cell B. If the cell is empty, it should not pull the date.  Like:

```
--------------------------------------
A           |  B
--------------------------------------
Paid        |  2/25/2018
----------------------------------
Paid        | 2/26/2018 
----------------------------------
empty cell  |   
----------------------------------
empty cell  |  




I tried to use =ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A81=paid),"paid",(NOW()))
```

But getting error. Is their any way to do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A81="paid", NOW(),""))
```

If you never want the date to change, you need to use script like this:

```
function onEdit() {
  // writes the current date to the cell to the right on the row when a cell in a specific column is edited
  // adjust the following variables to fit your needs

  var sheetNameToWatch = "Sheet1";
  var columnNumberToWatch = /* column A */ 1; // column A = 1, B = 2, etc.
  var valueToWatch="paid";

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var val=sheet.getActiveCell().getValue()

  if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && val==valueToWatch) {
    var targetCell = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), range.getColumn()+1
                               );
    targetCell.setValue("" + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "MM/dd/yyyy"));
  }
}
```

There is not a way to do this with a formula that I know of. It can be made shorter, but script is still required:

```
function onEdit(e) {
   if (e.source.getSheetName()=="Sheet1" && e.range.getColumn() == 1 && e.range.getValue() == "paid") {
      e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(new Date());
  }}
```

Comment: Can you explain  "never want the date to change"  is the formula not set date that never change?

Comment: With now() in the if formula, when you open the spreadsheet tomorrow the date will be tomorrows date.

Comment: is their any formula to do this.. if i dont want to use this script?

Comment: I implanted the ARRAYFORMULA solution the problem, it is taking all the dates of the day I introduced this formula and If I change it, The ARRAYFORMULA will obviously show error

Answer (score 1):

Works perfectly, thank you!

I changed it a little, so the date would auto populate if I entered anything into the column. I keep several spreedsheets for accounting, billing, and business tracking. One of them is hours. So when I enter the hours "1" or "5.5", the date to the left will populate. Love it! Thanks.

```
function onEdit() {
  // writes the current date to the cell to the right on the row when a cell in a specific column is edited
  // adjust the following variables to fit your needs

  var sheetNameToWatch = "Sheet1";
  var columnNumberToWatch = /* column A */ 2; // column A = 1, B = 2, etc.
  var valueToWatch="paid"; /* isn't doing anything */

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var val=sheet.getActiveCell().getValue()

  if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && val!= "" /* I changed this var value so if I input anything, it will update the date */) {
    var targetCell = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), range.getColumn()-1 /* changed this to "-1" so it will input to the left column */
                               );
    targetCell.setValue("" + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "MM/dd/yyyy"));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not quite an exact answer, but [a simple and quick way to add the current date](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/107763/258966) to a cell is:

- <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd> (on Mac keyboard, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> otherwise)

Comment: This works on desktop, but is there an easy way to insert the current date when using the Android/iOS app?