# Automatic date formula google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm a spreadsheet newbie and can not find the answer to this. When I type in c11 and all future entrants in column C, I would like the current date to auto add to column A. How do I do this? This date will remain the same.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Seems to be similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989962/how-to-autofill-date-in-google-sheet-when-i-enter-value-in-cell-a

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to autofill date in google sheet when i enter value in cell A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989962/how-to-autofill-date-in-google-sheet-when-i-enter-value-in-cell-a)

Comment: possible only with script